# how to pass data from one model into another loopback

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

guys, I m new to loopback so don't know how I can do. here is my code

```
 module.exports = function(Customer) {

    Customer.beforeRemote('create', function (ctx, user, next) {
    var companyprofile=app.models.customerdetail
    companyprofile.create(ctx.args.data.cust_cmp_profile,user,next)// is this possible to pass selected value to model customerdetail
    console.log(ctx);
    });
};
```

both model is unrelated so i call  customerdetail model in Customer here i m try to use create method of customerdetail but don't know how to do that . i search lot but have't got any thing how i can do this

Comment: I believe you want the "Working with Data" docs here: http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Working-with-data.html. This describes how to CRUD data via the server-side APIs.

Comment: @RaymondCamden I m calling  customerdetail in  customer model.. the  link which you gave haven't provide any examples. can you give me any example related to my question and thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

try this hope it will help you

```
    Customer.beforeRemote('create', function (ctx, user, next) {

   var companyprofile=app.models.customerdetail
   companyprofile.create({cust_cmp_profile:ctx.args.data.cust_cmp_profile},              function(err) {
    if (err){
        next(err)
     } 
    else{
        next()
    }
 });   
});
```

Comment: even i want to pass the data from one module to another. so i have added the above according my requirement but it throws an error like companyprofile is not defined.. In place of companyprofile i have used my module name.

Comment: @lakshmipriya   var companyprofile=app.models.customerdetail . "customerdetail" is you model name check you name provided after app.models it should exact  same name given in particular(your model) json file

Comment: can u answer for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55568366/loopback-get-data-from-one-module-to-anothee because i want to fetch the attached filename in another module

Comment: I want to pass the file name from attachment module to career module

Answer (score 0):

To have `app` available in your model you should do the following:

```js
module.exports = function(Customer) {
  let app
  
  // Your code like app.models
  
  Customer.on('attached', function(a) {
    app = a
  })
}
```

Comment: above code also worked well, anyway thanks for your suggestion