# Loopback get data from one module to anothee

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

I am using loopback3 for file storage attachment.js and i have the persistedmodel  career.js for storing the data. Now i want to fetch the file name in the career.js. how to do this.

career.js

```
'use strict';
const app = require('../../server/server');
module.exports = function(Career) {

    Career.afterRemote('create', function(context, remoteMethodOutput, next) { 
        next(); 
     // console.log(context.result) 
    Career.app.models.Email.send({ 
            to: 'john@gmail.com', 
            from: 'noreply@gmail.com', 
            subject: 'Career Form', 
            html: '<em>Hi,</em>'

            },
           function(err, mail) { 
                // console.log(context.result.email)
            console.log('email sent!'); 
            console.log(err); 
        }); 
    });
```

attachment.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(Attachment) {

};
```

Comment: Which file name and of which location, you want to fetch in career.js? Can you be more clear?

Comment: @ shubhambharti201 I have the form with name, message and file input. now i can able to fetch the values of name and message in the career.js once it is submitted . but i want to fetch the attached filename also in the career.js

Answer (score 0):

call your other model over here. as per my understanding, you try to insert file name. so I modified your code.

```
'use strict';
const app = require('../../server/server');
module.exports = function(Career) {

Career.afterRemote('create', function(context, remoteMethodOutput, next) { 
var companyprofile=app.models."yourmodel" // model name from where you want to insert file name
 companyprofile.create({cust_cmp_profile:context.args.data.cust_cmp_profile},              
  function(err) {
    if (err){
       next(err)
    } 
  else{
      next()
  }
});   

 // console.log(context.result) 
Career.app.models.Email.send({ 
        to: 'john@gmail.com', 
        from: 'noreply@gmail.com', 
        subject: 'Career Form', 
        html: '<em>Hi,</em>'

        },
       function(err, mail) { 
            // console.log(context.result.email)
        console.log('email sent!'); 
        console.log(err); 
    }); 
});
```

hope this help

Comment: am getting an error ReferenceError: ctx is not defined

Comment: I want to get the attached file name in the career.js

Comment: I can able to get the file name in the attachment.js module using afterRemote method, but i want to get in the career.js module

Comment: @lakshmipriya solution which I gave is a stander

Comment: but am getting the error as ctx is not defined. could you please check

Comment: @lakshmipriya update my answer use context instead of ctx if you find my answer please select as correct and upvote it

Comment: so where can i print and check the file name

Comment: @lakshmipriya CONTEXT contain all info console.log(context) and find your file name in it

Comment: thank you but am getting an error like  companyprofile.create is not a function

Comment: @lakshmipriya use like this  app.models."yourmodel".create(

Comment: app.models.Attachment.create is not a function still am getting the same error could you please help me